# If $A^2=O$, then prove that $I+A$ is invertible and find $(I+A)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I'm stuck on this Linear Algebra question. My first (naive) train of thought here was to go through with an implication that $A^2=O$ implies $A=O$. Then this got quickly debunked having read up on nilpotent matrices.

So I'm back to square one without a clue as to how to proceed. Any hints will be much appreciated on where to begin with this, has been pestering me for at least one day now.

EDIT: Thank you everyone, very happy for all your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried to use a difference of squares?

Comment: Use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to properly format equations.

Comment: Hint : $(I-A)(I+A)=I^2-A^2=I$

Comment: Note that in general, $AB\ne BA$, but $AI=IA=A$ is true for every matrix $A$, so the terms $AI$ and $IA$ actually cancel out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that $A^2=0$, the inverse of $I+A$ is apparent from the identity
$$(I+A)(I-A)=I-A^2=I.$$

Comment: Ah yes! That is brilliant. Thank you so much, very grateful for that. Very silly of me to have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

$A^2=O$ suggests that the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$ with multiplicity $n$, where $A$ is a square of order $n$. Now, eigenvalues of $A+I$ will be $0+1=1$ (Why?), which tells us that $A+I$ is invertible (Why?)